# Mongo db query criteria with regEx for both key and value

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot, mongodb-query, spring-data-mongodb

Is it possible to have a mongo query criteria with regEx for both field name and field value. I don't know the exact field name which matches the given field value.

Below one works if I pass the field name and regex field value

Criteria.where("field1").regex("^united$")

But I have a problem where I don't know the exact field name. Do we have something like

Criteria.regex("^field$").regex("^united$")

Comment: You could accomplish this using an aggregation pipeline that utilized the `$objectToArray` operator, but this is not going to scale well and may not be fast enough for you after the collection grows beyond a trivial size. Indexes can't help with such a query